# A/B testing strategies & gems for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ab-testing

I'd like to do A/B testing for my views and I was wondering what gems are out there and what strategies you can suggest.

I already found http://www.bingocardcreator.com/abingo but I can't tell if that does entire templates as well, or just buttons, etc.

suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also [Vanity](http://vanity.labnotes.org/) and Google Website Optimizer